# How to zoom out React-Native map

Tags: ios, dictionary, react-native

Hi I just begin to use react-native. How to restricted from zooming out and in too much on react-native map? Is there a var that i can set to to limit the zooming?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the values from `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` inside your props `region` in `<MapView />`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-map then you have props called `minZoomLevel` and `maxZoomLevel`
you can add these props and give the number between `0` to `20`. the default value for min is `0` and the default value for the max is `20` as per the documentation.

You can use as below

```
<MapView
    minZoomLevel={5} 
    maxZoomLevel={10}
>
</MapView>
```

refer : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

Answer (score -2):

yes, you can use "maxDelta" and "minDelta" to achieve that.

Comment: You could perhaps add more information, such as an example, to make your answer more useful.

Comment: minDelta and maxDelta are not implemented yet even if they are already in the code but not in the doc.

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/components/MapView.js